# How does .insert work?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out what the `insert` function does in Ruby.

I've consulted Google and ruby-doc.com but the explanation is not sufficient to describe this (seemingly) mysterious function.

Here's what's confusing me:

```
a = %w{a b c d}
puts a.insert(4, 5)  output = a,b,c,d,5
```

The first question raised is, why is the 4 not inserted?

```
puts a.insert(2,2,6)
```

The output is:

```
a
b
2
6
c
d
```

Two questions raised by this are

1. Why is 2 not inserted twice?
2. Why are 2 and six (seemingly) arbitrarily placed between b and c?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I'm not sure what the confusion is. From the Ruby docs:

```
ary.insert(index, obj...)  -> ary
```

> Inserts the given values before the element with the given index (which may be
>   negative).

```
a = %w{ a b c d }
a.insert(2, 99)         #=> ["a", "b", 99, "c", "d"]
a.insert(-2, 1, 2, 3)   #=> ["a", "b", 99, "c", 1, 2, 3, "d"]
```

So, `a.insert(2, 99)` is inserting `99` into the array just before array offset 2. Remember that an array's index starts at 0, so that is the *third* slot in the array.

The second example is inserting the array `[1,2,3]` into the second-from-the-last array slot, because negative offsets count from the end of the array. `-1` is the last index, `-2` is the second to last.

The Array docs say it well:

> Array indexing
>   starts at 0, as in C or Java.  A negative index is assumed to be relative to
>   the end of the array---that is, an index of -1 indicates the last element of
>   the array, -2 is the next to last element in the array, and so on.

These are VERY important concepts to learn in programming in general, not just in Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the first parameter is the index to insert at, and the rest are the items to insert.

The [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000230) would appear to confirm this, listing the function as `ary.insert(index, obj...) → ary`

If you simply want to add some values to the end of the array (I don't know Ruby syntax but this should be correct) I think you will want to call `a.insert(a.length, 4, 5)` or `a.insert(a.length, 2, 2, 6)`, for example.

Comment: If you simply want to add some values to the end of the array, use [`Array#push`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000226) method.